# Convexity Adjustment for Average Rate IRS

Tags: pricing, interest-rate-swap, convexity, adjustments

Suppose that one want to price an Interest Rate Swap with daily averaging, i.e. the floating leg looks like

$$Floating~Leg = \sum\limits_{i=1}^N P(T_i)\cdot\frac{\sum_{k=1}^m F(t_k, t_k+\delta)}{m}, ~T_{i-1}\leq t_k< T_i$$

It seems like some sort of convexity adjustment is needed there since some of rates are maturing before the natural payment time and some are maturing afterwards. In essense this a mix of cases discussed in Brigo & Mercurio book (13.8.5 Forward Rate Resetting Unnaturally and Average-Rate Swaps) and [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/29740/what-is-the-correct-convexity-adjustment-for-an-interest-rate-swap-with-unnatura).